# Set an entire xml layout file as the content of an alert dialog

Tags: android

For example, say I have a layout file that is a relative layout and has many buttons and text fields etc etc, and the background is transparent.

Is it possible to use this file as the content for a alert dialog (or some sort of pop up) so when I create the dialog, the layout contents will show? Also, I want the background to still be shown, that is why I've declared the layout file's background as transparent.

Is this possible to implement, if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Try to use dialog this method : setContentView(yourLayout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it easily:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dlg);
dialog.setTitle("Custom dialog");
```

And you are done. You can refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) tutorial for more details.

Comment: I didn't know you could call setContentView on dialogs. Thanks for that!

Comment: Glad that I could help :) @Ogen Happy coding.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I thought your answer was perfect. :D

Comment: I know you didn't. Someone else did. And didn't even point out why!

Comment: It could be someone who didn't get their answer accepted. I don't know why this question is being downvoted, I'm sure it's not THAT bad...

Comment: May be. No problem. I did my part. Was able to help. That's what is important :) happy coding. time to leave.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create custom dialogs in android. below is the code snippet you would need to do this.

**Custom dialog xml file: custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFF" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Ok "
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Simple main activity xml with a button: main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonShowCustomDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Custom Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And once you have set this up in your MainActivity.java file you can click the button and popup the custom dialog as following,

**In your MainActivity.java file**

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
      }
    });
```